# Why does :p freeze in GHCi when I give it this corecursive value?

Tags: haskell, ghci, corecursion

I've defined the infinite list of infinite lists `pathCounts` and the infinite list of finite lists `pathCounts'`:

```
import Data.Function (fix)

nextRow xs = fix $ \ys -> zipWith (+) xs (0:ys)

pathCounts = repeat 1 : map nextRow pathCounts
pathCounts' = map (take 100) pathCounts
```

Dropping into ghci, if I haven't evaluated either at all, I can use `:p` on either successfully:

```
ghci> :p pathCounts
pathCounts = (_t1::[[Integer]])
ghci> :p pathCounts'
pathCounts' = (_t2::[[Integer]])
```

But if I evaluate `pathCounts'` partially, then `:p` freezes on `pathCounts` while still succeeding on `pathCounts'`:

```
ghci> head . head $ pathCounts'
1
ghci> :p pathCounts'
pathCounts' = (1 : (_t4::[Integer])) : (_t5::[[Integer]])
ghci> :p pathCounts
^CInterrupted.
```

I'd expect `:p pathCounts` to print the same as `:p pathCounts'`, as I've only partially evaluated it.  Why isn't it working?

Comment: I'm not sure why it is causing this, but you generate a space leak by calling `:p pathCounts` that last time.  Examine your RAM usage in your system monitor when you call it, mine jumped up to full usage pretty quickly.  My guess would be that for whatever reason the partial evaluation of `pathCounts'` then makes `:p pathCounts` try to evaluate the `repeat 1` term of `pathCounts`.  What happens if you try `head . head . tail $ pathCounts'`?  I would assume you get a space leak again.

Comment: yeah, `pathCounts'` is a bit of a distraction - I was just trying to demonstrate that `:p` worked for a partially evaluated infinite list of finite lists. The leak happens if I inspect any part of `pathCounts`, directly or indirectly.

Comment: Simpler example `ghci> let pcs = repeat $ repeat 1 :: [Int]`, `ghci> pcs !! 0 !! 0`, `ghci> :p pcs`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> I'd expect `:p pathCounts` to print the same as `:p pathCounts'`, as I've only partially evaluated it.

Ah, but that's the interesting bit! You have, in fact, *fully* evaluated the (infinitely long) head of `pathCounts`. Let's take a slightly smaller example to simplify the discussion:

```
> let v = repeat 1 :: [Int]
> head v
1
> :p v
^C
```

I claim that after fully evaluating `head v`, in fact `v` is also fully evaluated. This is because, in memory, `v` is a cyclic singly-linked list. So if you've evaluated enough to know the first element, there is nothing left to evaluate!

The result is that when you ask to `:print` it, GHC duly attempts to construct a string representing all of the evaluated portion of the structure -- and obviously can't, since it will never stop traversing. (`:p` simply doesn't have a way to indicate sharing in a structure.)

Compare:

```
> let x = 1 :: Int; v = (x, x)
> fst v
1
> :p v
(1,1)
```

Although you have only requested evaluation of the first part of `v`, in fact all of `v` has been evaluated here, so `:p` prints it all -- and doesn't indicate the sharing that exists between the first and second parts.

Now, how come `pathCounts'` doesn't have the same problem? Well, the thing there is that, although `map f (repeat x) = repeat (f x)` is a denotationally correct equation, in the GHC implementation of Haskell, that equation isn't operationally sound -- and `:p` is all about the operational semantics and thumbs its nose at the denotational semantics. In particular, `map` doesn't (can't) observe the sharing present in `repeat x`; hence it produces a non-cyclic infinite list. Since `map f (repeat x)` has less sharing, forcing part of `map f (repeat x)` doesn't result in an in-memory representation that is as fully evaluated.

Comment: btw in common lisp and scheme (I think, at least some dialects), and even prolog, they do have ways to show the circularity in structures...

Comment: @WillNess We have ways to do that in Haskell, too -- it's just that `:p` doesn't use them. See e.g. [vacuum-cairo](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/vacuum-cairo).

Comment: thanks for the link (I *knew* I saw something like that once!) -- a side note: so this problem here is only with `pathCounts`'s head, by the same reasoning for `zipWith`  as for `map`...

Comment: @WillNess Aha, thanks for the comment. Now I understand Reid Barton's complaint better. You (and he) are right, of course, and my earlier rebuttal just looks silly now. =D